# nodejs facebook messenger bot admin or editor id instead of page id

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, facebook-messenger, bottender

i'm using bottender & nodejs to create a bot messenger , but i got a problem when i try to retrieve the user id of a (admin or editor) in my page to know who send the response to a user in the page.
 this is what i got :

```
{ sender: { id: '868761280555360' },
  recipient: { id: '787381751469' },
  timestamp: 1515780811774,
  message: 
   { is_echo: true,
     mid: 'mid.$cAAUU4wBJk8VnHNjz_lg65PqOOZXZ',
     seq: 361916,
     text: 'hi' } }
```

**sender** : is the id of page and not the admin id for example.

**recipient**: user id who contact the page.

any one has a idea how i can get a sender id (admin or editor) of a page instead of page id with bottender.

Answer (score 2):

The message was sent from the actual page. Even if there is an admin or editor who sent the message, he was using the page's identity, therefore is not possible to detect who actually sent the message.

You could tell your admins or editors to use a signature in the message. Split the message and get the admin's name.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get the sender behind the page, as facebook offcial docunment stated, here's a receiveing text message webhook event example:

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PAGE_ID>"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "message":{
    "mid":"mid.1457764197618:41d102a3e1ae206a38",
    "text":"hello, world!",
    "quick_reply": {
      "payload": "<DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD>"
    }
  }
}
```

ref:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/message-echoes

BTW, you can always check the rawEvent received when using bottender, with `context.event.rawEvent`.
It would be helpful sometimes.

Comment: Please add the most relevant parts of the linked website to your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52366877/edit) it, in case that the target page gets unavailable or the information get invalidated.